# How to change global variable through function?

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a way to change a global variable within a function in Python without passing it in as a parameter?

```
test = 5
print(test)
def changeTest():
    test = 10
    return

#no effect.  test still equals 5
print(test)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify that you want to use the global version of 'test' rather than a local one

```
test = 5

print(test)

def changeTest():
    global test //added this line
    test = 10
    return

changeTest()

print(test) //prints 10
```

Comment: Awesome!  Can you explain what is happening?  It is a redeclare of the variable?

Comment: It specifies that you want to use a global variable - which in this case is 'test';. without this, the function creates/declares a local version and gives it the value you gave it. using 'global' is only needed when you want to modify a global variable.

Comment: @4thSpace: Anyway, you should avoid global variables. They are rarely needed. Mostly, it is the sign of a bad design.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have not called the function so test will never be given the value 10.